# Probability of two variables

Tags: probability

I have some questions about the following joint pdfs:

**1.** I have to evaluate $P(X>Y)$ where
$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle\frac{12}{7}(x^2+xy), & 0<x,y<1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

I want to know if it's right:

$$P(X>Y)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1} \frac{12}{7}(x^{2}+xy) dxdy$$

**2.** If
$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle\frac{x}{5}+\frac{y}{25}, & 0<x<1,\quad0<y<5 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

I drew the rectangle and I concluded that
$$P(X+Y>3)=P(Y>3+X)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{3+x}^{5}\left(\frac{x}{5}+\frac{y}{25}\right)dydx$$

Are these integrals correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is correct and in the second one, you have a small mistake.

First one can also be written as,

$ \displaystyle P(X>Y)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{12}{7}(x^{2}+xy) \ dy \ dx$

For second one, $P(X+Y \gt 3)  = P(Y \gt 3 - X)$

So it should be,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_{3-x}^5 \left(\frac{x}{5}+\frac{y}{25}\right) \ dy \ dx$